# Inefficient covering by translates

Tags: discrete-geometry, packing-and-covering

While trying to answer [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312493/what-is-the-expected-value-of-the-submeasure-of-a-random-set), I arrived at another question:

> How many translates of $\{0,1\}^n$ does it take to cover $\mathbb F_3^n$?

The broader context is: consider a set $S$ and a collection $\mathcal P$ of subsets of $S$; each subset of the same size, $t$, and each element of $S$ belonging to the same number, $k$, of elements of $\mathcal P$. Write $N(S,\mathcal P)$ for the minimal number of elements of $\mathcal P$ to cover $S$.

By analogy with definitions about covering and packing of subsets of $\mathbb R^d$, define the *covering density* of $\mathcal P$ to be $t\times N(S,\mathcal P)/|S|$, that is the average number of times than an element of $S$ is covered by a minimal covering from $\mathcal P$.

By random methods, I can show that one can find $n\times (\frac 32)^n$ translates of $\{0,1\}^n$ that cover $\mathbb F_3^n$ for a covering density of at most $n$.

Are there any known lower bounds on the covering density?

Are there well known places to look for good examples with large covering density?

Are random methods the standard approach to questions of this type?